# Elixir - Get all PIDs for processes under a supervisor

Tags: elixir, erlang-otp

I have a Supervisor and want to know all the processes running under that Supervisor at any given time. It seems like there should be an easy way to get all PIDs, names, etc. for all processes under a Supervisor or in a node, but I can't find anything.

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Comment: For future reference the Elixir Supervisor module is documented here: http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use [Supervisor.which_children/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html#which_children/1):

```
iex> Supervisor.which_children(MyApp.Supervisor)
[{MyApp.SubSupervisor, #PID<0.1695.0>, :supervisor, [MyApp.SubSupervisor]},
 {MyApp.Endpoint, #PID<0.1686.0>, :supervisor, [MyApp.Endpoint]}]
```

> Returns a list with information about all children of the given
>   supervisor.
>
> Note that calling this function when supervising a large number of
>   children under low memory conditions can cause an out of memory
>   exception.
>
> This function returns a list of `{id, child, type, modules}` tuples,
>   where:
>
> - **`id`** - as defined in the child specification
> - **`child`** - the PID of the corresponding child process, `:restarting` if the
>     process is about to be restarted, or `:undefined` if there is no such
>     process
> - **`type`** - `:worker` or `:supervisor`, as specified by the child specification
> - **`modules`** - as specified by the child specification

Since the `type` and `pid` are provided you can recursively fetch the children to generate a list of all the pids if required.